# Best way to set up a shared drive for a company using Linux (eg. Ubuntu Server)?

Tags: ftp, mount, drive

I am trying to find out the best way to set up a shared drive for a company which has 50+ users in 3 office locations in different cities.

They basically need a drive with a common folder to store company documents (eg. /home/company-docs/) plus a personal folder for each user (eg. /home/username/mydocs/). They will mainly access the drive from Windows 7 machines and few Ubuntu machines.

They cannot use an external application such as Dropbox, Google Drive and so on (for regulatory and compliance reasons).

I am currently using Ubuntu server 14.04 with ProFTPD, and the machines access the server drive using WinSCP or Filezilla. For permissions I am using ACL.

The tricky part is the folder structure so everyone can see the common folder (/home/company-docs) and the personal folder (/home/username/mydocs) in their home directory.

Using ProFTPD I can chroot jail the users to their home directory and there mydocs/ folder is created (using skel).

But how can I give them access to the company folder which is located outside their home folder (path is /home/company-docs)???

My first option is to mount /home/company-docs/ in the user home:

```
mount --bind /home/company-docs/ /home/user_name/company-docs
```

And then make this configuration permanent by editing /etc/fstab:

```
/var/www/dev  /home/user_name/www_dev    none    bind    0       0
```

But the above solution works for just 1 particular user, how can I make this work for every user in the system and make it permanent for every user? and also how to set it up automatically when a new user is created?

Please let me know if you have any idea on how to accomplish this or any other better way you may think on doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows machines should be able to use Samba to mount their drives.  The Samba documentation covers this scenario in detail.

For linux machines you can use NFS to mount the required shares.  I use automount rules to mount home directories.

Both these options should work over VPN for traveling users.